# How to serve phpMyAdmin to localhost/phpMyAdmin instead of localhost:8080 using nginx in docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, phpmyadmin, nginx-reverse-proxy

In my project, I am using Django and nginx, but I want to manage my cloud databases through phpmyadmin.

Django is working fine but I can't do the same with phpmyadmin because it is running in apache at localhost:8080, when I want it to run in nginx at localhost/phpmyadmin.

here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:

  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./project:/project
    expose:
      - 8000
      
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./static:/static
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: <host_address>
      PMA_USER: <user>
      PMA_PASSWORD: <password>
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

and nginx default.conf

```
upstream django{
    server web:8000;
}

server{
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /pma/ {               
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;                                 
        proxy_buffering off;                                     
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

I hope somebody will be able to tell me how to make nginx work as a reverse proxy for the phpMyAdmin docker container.

If some important information is missing please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access another docker container with its hostname and the internal port (not the exposed one).
Also a rewrite of the url is necessary.

```
    location  ~ \/pma {
      rewrite ^/pma(/.*)$ $1 break;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin;
    }
```

I tested with this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:      
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
    ports:
      - 80:80

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @varchar42, you made my day!!